OSX Sonoma fresh brew of mariadb, php unable to load pdo-mysql
We are tearing our hair out!  We brewed mariadb and php but continue to get errors when running php.  Just a command like: php -v
Error like this:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/pdo_mysql.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Tried this: pecl install pdo_mysql
The error was then:
running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootn6o3Ff/install-PDO-1.0.3" install
Installing shared extensions:     /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootn6o3Ff/install-PDO-1.0.3/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.7/pecl/20230831/
cp: modules/*: No such file or directory
make: * [install-modules] Error 1

This is on Sonoma OSX with PHP 8.2
We have tried reinstalling mariadb and php.
Please help.

Has the system worked with previous PHP versions, or is this a new instance?

This has been running (and maintained) for about 16 years.  This is the first time on OSX (with Sonoma) that we have had issues getting these products to work together.
At this stage we have ditched the implementation and gone to a MAMP download.  It's working much better and setup much quicker, although configuring the settings takes a little longer to find the right file.

We started again with MAMP and this worked fine.  Sorry we couldn't solve this.
